# Using CASE to compare DISTINCT(COUNT()) and COUNT() columns

Tags: sql

I want to run a query that will return 'Yes' when the distinct count and count return the same value. Below is the unsuccessful query.

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT(COUNT(colA)),
  COUNT(colA),
CASE
  WHEN DISTINCT(COUNT(colA)) = COUNT(colA) THEN 'Yes'
  ELSE 'Sad'
END
FROM tableA
```

Comment: `distinct` is **not** a function. It always applies to **all** columns in the select list. Enclosing one of the columns with parentheses won't change anything and is useless. `distinct (a),b` is the same as `distinct a,(b)` or `distinct a,b`

Comment: Perhaps you want `COUNT(DISTINCT colA)`?

Answer (score 4):

you need to count distinct like so :

```
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT colA),
    COUNT(colA),
    CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT colA) = COUNT(colA) THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'Sad' END
FROM tableA
```